# Getting published in a course-based grad program

Tags: publications, phd, research-process, masters

I was wondering if anyone has any advice about how I can get published despite being in a course-based masters program. I am currently pursuing a master of public health in health promotion, but I have never been published before and would like to apply for a PhD program eventually. I have heard people have done literature reviews on topics before, is this an option?

I appreciate any help and insight you can provide! I really do not know much about academia.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way to get started doing research is to find an experienced advisor to guide you. Also, if you would like to apply to a PhD program, you will need strong recommendation letters from faculty who can speak to your ability to do research (and not just your ability to earn good grades in your coursework).

Talk to faculty in your department (ideally, those you've left a positive impression on as a student in their courses) about participating in their research.